# crosstab.r outputs in list. to get this is displayed in a table?

Tags: r

So, i found this really nice crosstab function that really has all the features I want: 
http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r

The output of this function is a list, using this example:
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6975_c4943349b6174f448104a5513fed59a9.html

Now I want to have this output displayed in datatables... 
That is where I loose it. The  list has a number of tables in it. 
My plan is to make a shiny widget that allows me to load a dataset and set parameters and have a decent looking crosstab as a result.

Comment: Which of those examples would you want to convert to a table?

Comment: crosstab(Survey, row.vars = c("Age", "Sex"), col.vars = "Health", type = "j")   Any of the examples, but if I can have the above i will know how to deal with all the other options

Comment: If you had that stored as "x", you can access the tables using `x$table` and `x$crosstab`. Those are going to be multi-dimensional arrays, though. To make them nice and rectangular, you can try out the `ftable2dt` function from [my SOfun package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun) (as in `ftable2dt(x$table)`).

Comment: That is, I'm assuming you want to convert these to rectangular tables....

Comment: That does the trick! Great help, thanks!!!

Comment: OK. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have:

```
x <- crosstab(Survey, row.vars = c("Age", "Sex"), col.vars = "Health", type = "j")
```

Which looks like:

```
x
##              Health Average   Good   Poor    Sum
## Age   Sex                                       
## 0-15  Female          15.38  25.64  25.64  66.67
##       Male             7.69  15.38  10.26  33.33
##       Sum             23.08  41.03  35.90 100.00
## 16-29 Female          22.22  19.44  11.11  52.78
##       Male            19.44  19.44   8.33  47.22
##       Sum             41.67  38.89  19.44 100.00
## 30-44 Female           6.45  19.35  12.90  38.71
##       Male            22.58  19.35  19.35  61.29
##       Sum             29.03  38.71  32.26 100.00
## 45-64 Female          15.15   9.09  27.27  51.52
##       Male             9.09  18.18  21.21  48.48
##       Sum             24.24  27.27  48.48 100.00
## 65+   Female          15.79   7.89  21.05  44.74
##       Male            13.16  26.32  15.79  55.26
##       Sum             28.95  34.21  36.84 100.00
```

And has a `str`ucture that looks like:

```
str(x)
## List of 10
##  $ row.vars   : int [1:2] 1 2
##  $ col.vars   : int 3
##  $ dec.places : num 2
##  $ type       : chr "joint.pct"
##  $ style      : chr "wide"
##  $ percentages: logi TRUE
##  $ addmargins : logi TRUE
##  $ subtotals  : logi TRUE
##  $ table      : table [1:5, 1:3, 1:4] 6 8 2 5 6 3 7 7 3 5 ...
##   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
##   .. ..$ Age   : chr [1:5] "0-15" "16-29" "30-44" "45-64" ...
##   .. ..$ Sex   : chr [1:3] "Female" "Male" "Sum"
##   .. ..$ Health: chr [1:4] "Average" "Good" "Poor" "Sum"
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "table" "array"
##  $ crosstab   : table [1:5, 1:3, 1:4] 15.38 22.22 6.45 15.15 15.79 ...
##   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
##   .. ..$ Age   : chr [1:5] "0-15" "16-29" "30-44" "45-64" ...
##   .. ..$ Sex   : chr [1:3] "Female" "Male" "Sum"
##   .. ..$ Health: chr [1:4] "Average" "Good" "Poor" "Sum"
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "table" "array"
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr "crosstab"
## NULL
```

You can try:

```
library(SOfun)
ftable2dt(x$crosstab)
##       Age    Sex   Average      Good      Poor       Sum
##  1:  0-15 Female 15.384615 25.641026 25.641026  66.66667
##  2:  0-15   Male  7.692308 15.384615 10.256410  33.33333
##  3:  0-15    Sum 23.076923 41.025641 35.897436 100.00000
##  4: 16-29 Female 22.222222 19.444444 11.111111  52.77778
##  5: 16-29   Male 19.444444 19.444444  8.333333  47.22222
##  6: 16-29    Sum 41.666667 38.888889 19.444444 100.00000
##  7: 30-44 Female  6.451613 19.354839 12.903226  38.70968
##  8: 30-44   Male 22.580645 19.354839 19.354839  61.29032
##  9: 30-44    Sum 29.032258 38.709677 32.258065 100.00000
## 10: 45-64 Female 15.151515  9.090909 27.272727  51.51515
## 11: 45-64   Male  9.090909 18.181818 21.212121  48.48485
## 12: 45-64    Sum 24.242424 27.272727 48.484848 100.00000
## 13:   65+ Female 15.789474  7.894737 21.052632  44.73684
## 14:   65+   Male 13.157895 26.315789 15.789474  55.26316
## 15:   65+    Sum 28.947368 34.210526 36.842105 100.00000
```

(Or, alternatively, `ftable2dt(x$table)` if that is the data you're after.

Get [the SOfun package from GitHub](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).